# How to show Design View in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, visual-studio-2015

I am using Visual Studio 2015.

In my C# class at school we are designing a Windows Form App. We started the project in class, and checked it into our TFS so I can use it at home. I loaded it at home and under the design tab it just shows the code view, not the design view, but whenever I press "Start" it opens up and shows everything and lets me use save stuff and reopen them in the listbox.

So at home I am unable to see the design so I can't add buttons, textboxs, etc.

How am I able to make it show the design view and not just the code view?

Comment: In the Solution Explorer window, double click on your form or right click on it and select "View Designer". Is that what you're talking about?

Answer (score 2):

Try to highlight the [Formname].cs File in your solution explorer. Then press [Shift]+[F7]. This should do the Trick.